# Binomial coefficient, adding further 'combinations'

Tags: binomial-coefficients

As a programmer, discovering the binomial theorem has helped me with alot.
I want to solve something using maths as source and I wonder if you can help me define this one:

Regarding [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286330/how-many-combinations-of-20-balls-can-be-drawn-from-a-bag-of-10-blue-balls-and-a) question and its following outcome with: 
$${20 \choose 10} = 184756$$

I want to add further combinations. Say, every blue ball has a random letter written on it, **A-Z**(26 combinations), and red balls a number **0-9**(10 combinations).

The letters and numbers cannot be repeated in once instance. e.g. AABCDEFGHI1234567890 is not allowed because 'A' is repeated.

**There can be only ten blue and ten red balls in the bag.**

How do I express this mathematically to calculate all the possible combinations?

Comment: thank you, I made the edit

Comment: Do you still have ten balls of each colour? How are the labels distributed? Perhaps it would be best to simply re-ask the question with the new parameters.

Comment: yes you are right, im missing out on some params. edited again, sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So unless I'm misunderstanding something, you're essentially asking for the number of possible strings of length $20$ where exactly $10$ of the characters are digits and the other $10$ are letters, with no repetitions.

I think we can simply modify the previous solution. There are $\binom{20}{10}$ ways to place the red and blue balls (digits and letters). In each configuration, the first blue ball to be labelled has $26$ possible labels, the second has $25$, and so on. The first red ball to be labelled has $10$ possible labels, the second has $9$, and so on. In total this gives us $\binom{20}{10} \cdot \frac{26!}{(26-10)!} \cdot \frac{10!}{(10-10)!}$ possible strings.

Comment: Oops, I just saw that we are not allowed repetition. Let me edit quickly.

Comment: This looks almost correct. I think you should erase the $+1$ in both denominators, since essentially you are computing permutations as in $$26P10=\frac{26!}{(26-10)!}=\frac{26\cdot25\cdot...\cdot2\cdot1}{16\cdot15\cdot...\cdot2\cdot1}=26\cdot25\cdot...\cdot18\cdot17$$ and similarly for $10P10=10!$. Note that $(10-10)!=0!=1$ by definition. The definition is made so that $0!$ becomes neutral wrt. multiplication thus being the neutral element $1$ in that respect.

Comment: @String Right, I miscounted. Thank you.